# Django 2.0: back button redirecting to different pages based on where you came from

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I'm using Django 2.0 and have a model A with a list view and a detail view. You can go from the list view to the detail view in the following manner:

Button on `ListView Html` page to go to detail view

```
<td><a href="{{ a.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary" class>View</a></td>
```

Models.py

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("a:detail", kwargs={'a_id': self.a_id})
```

Then in the `DetailView Html Page` I have a button to go back to the detail view.

```
<a href="{% url 'a:list' %}" class="btn btn-primary" class>Back</a>
```

where a:list takes you to `ListView Html`

That is pretty straight forward. However, what if I made this same process for another html page. Then I'd need a second 'back' buttons to go to this new html page. It gets cumbersome really quick.

Is there a way that you can create a button that will go back to whatever page the user came from? This can either be to any page that has a button to go to this page (and you pass in some information that allows you to backtrack this) or maybe you typed in the url and want the back button to go back to whatever page you came from. I'm open to either way.

Comment: I think this is more a UI, UX problem. Browser's talibans would tell you "that's what the browser's back button is for!". But maybe you should first ask "> what do I want the user to go from here, > is there already a link? (from a navbar menu for example), > is really helpful the link or may confuse the user? > How do I want the information be presented? (maybe you could use modals or tabs for some content)", etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you need Back button you can simply use `HTTP_REFERER` header

Like this:

```
<a href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}" class="btn btn-primary" class>Back</a>
```

<sub>**Note:** you need to have `django.core.context_processors.request` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`.</sub>

Comment: For Django 4.0.4 I didn't even need to do anything to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`. Just adding `{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}` to the href nailed it for me. Thank you very much :)